# Displaying Map Annotation Callouts in a Specific Language

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, localization, mkmapview

I have an application with Google maps functionality using a MKMapView.

The application's language is Arabic. The application's users won't know English.

Is there any way to display annotation callout information in Arabic?

Answer (score 0):

The map will display in the language of the country it is displaying, often with English (or maybe your local language) as a second language. Open the Maps app on your phone and type in `Dubai` or `Cairo, Egypt`, for example, and you'll see Arabic text for cities and streets.

The same is true of other languages. Type `Shanghai, China` and you'll get Chinese text, `Tokyo, Japan` and you'll get Japanese text, etc.

Comment: ok i understand that . but in mapview in iphone i m showing title or address of that country. this name come in english only. how can i convert this in language wise ?

Comment: Where does the title or address come from? A database or MKReverseGeoCoder or somewhere else? Do you mean the language in an annotation?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the title and body of your question again so it better matches your question. Hopefully someone will see it and provide you with a good answer.

Comment: Are you asking what changes I made, or about how I made the changes? The changes I made were to make it clear you want to translate text in annotation callouts. I was able to change it because you can edit other people's questions here on Stack Overflow when you have at least 3,000 reputation.

Comment: ok. thnx ..but now how can i display annotation callout information in Arabic or any other language?

Comment: I don't know. I edited your question so someone who does know the answer might see it.